# how to search a number using binary search algorithm (without implementing any function) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary

Below is my complete code for binary search written in python3 version.
I was able to:-i) create a list, ii) sorted the list using bubble sort algorithm, iii)wrote code snippet for searching a number using binary search, 
But while searching for any number (which is present/not present in the list), my code goes into an infinite loop and does not gives any result. 
I tried looking for the error,But was unable to debug the code.

Also, how to get the index of the number in list? I thought of using list.index() method. Can it work in case of sorted list or my index number output will be wrongly displayed?

```
list=[]
item=0
while item!="99":
    item=input("Enter the number, To discontinue enter 99:")

    if item.isdigit(): #isdigit() checks whether input string consists of digits only
        list.append(int(item)) #convert the input string into number
    else:
        list.append(item)

del list[-1] #Delete the number at last index of the list. It will delete "99",
             #which we have used to discontinue the loop

print("The unsorted list is: ",list)

#Using bubble sort algorithm to sort the list
length=len(list)

for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length-1):
        if list[j]>list[j+1]:
            list[j],list[j+1]=list[j+1],list[j]

print("Our sorted list is: ",list)

#Implementing binary serach algorithm

target=int(input("Enter the number you are looking for: "))
first=0              #First index of list is 0
last=len(list)-1     #Last index of list is "length of list minus 1"
mid=(first+last)//2

while first<=last:
    if list[mid]<target:        #If element at middle index is less than the target element,shift new lower index to one more than middle index
        low=mid+1                     
    elif list[mid]==target:     #else, if element at middle index is same as target element
        print("Number is found at index")
        break
    else:
        last=mid-1
    mid=(first+last)//2
    if (first>last):
        print("Number not found in list")
```

Comment: What is the motivation for not implementing any function? That seems like an arbitrary restriction which is almost guaranteed to lead to bad code.

Comment: From the context, I bet this is homework, and what actually *was* in the question is he should not use a [standard python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), but that bit got misinterpreted.

Comment: You sometimes use `first` and sometimes `low` in your code. Probably the origin of the bug. Choose which it is and rename the other.

Comment: It is a part of assignment only and focused on to get it done without implementing function including standard python built ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop is from the line

```
low=mid+1
```

I think what you meant was

```
last=mid+1
```

The error was that the case `list[mid]<target` would happen, but since `low` is being changed not `last`, `mid` never changes the case will be triggered again on the next iteration.

EDIT: Also note that `mid` is the index of the number in the list

Comment: You were absolutely right. Thanks for that catch. Perhaps I got messed up with so many terms(first, last, mid) and complex algorithm and made that mistake...